# How can get the right size images when setting some resource to imageview?

Tags: android, gridview, imageview

I hope to put some item into a gridview like following :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/llBg"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="40dp" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/mudImg"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/icon_m0_r"
    android:visibility="visible" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/mudTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="fsafdsf"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="16dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

While the 'mudImg' part got something wrong with the image's size on a true android machine.Actually It never works util I set a indeed num to 'layout_width' and 'layout_height' like '50dp' or something like this.
  What I want is show the origin size image and if necessary expended to the size what the parent view left to it.
Now my solution is that calculating the image size with app screen params(height width) and parent view's margins and gridview's numColumns and setting the result by code (since can not do it in xml)
any better idea?

Comment: what is the purpose of the image? is it a background or some other thing?

Comment: It's local resource which binded by imageview (see android: src)

Comment: the reason that I'm asking is that in LinearLayout if you set the image size to match_parent then there would be no place for the TextView. Anyway if you want to have more freedom to play with images and texts it is better to use RelativeLayout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for your `ImageView`:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/mudImg"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@drawable/icon_m0_r"
    android:visibility="visible" />
```

`adjustViewBounds="true"` tells the `ImageView` to set the height so that the image has the correct aspect ratio using the given width.